# How do I get the HTTP Status Code from an Exception thrown in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently integrating some logic in App/Exceptions/Handler.php. I would like to be able to access the HTTP Status Code on the $exception variable:

```
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    dd($exception->statusCode);
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

However I get the following error:

> ErrorException Undefined property: ErrorException::$statusCode

When I `dd($exception)` I get the following:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException {#1214 ▼
  -statusCode: 404
  -headers: []
  #message: ""
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\Users\CEX\Documents\GitHub\unified\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php"
  #line: 43
  trace: {▶}
}
```

How do I access the `statusCode`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException` you will find that it extends `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` if you look at the declaration of the class you will see that `$statusCode` is private but it has a getter method

```php
class HttpException extends \RuntimeException implements HttpExceptionInterface
{
    private $statusCode;
    private $headers;

    public function __construct(int $statusCode, string $message = null, \Throwable $previous = null, array $headers = [], ?int $code = 0)
    {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        $this->headers = $headers;

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function getStatusCode()
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }
    //...
}
```

As such you simply need to do `$exception->getStatusCode()` to retrieve the status code (404 in your case) though you should do a check to make sure your throwable implements the `HttpExceptionInterface` because that might not always be the case and so the method would not exist and you would get a fatal error

```php
if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface) {
  $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you think of any edge cases where a different kind of exception may be thrown, so that I could test this out please?

Comment: Any other exception thrown in your code like `LogicException` or a php error can be caught as a throwable and be reported, you can check it by `throw new LogicException('')` within your controller and see what you get, the NotFoundHttpException is likely only thrown because your route is not being matched but you can definitely have non HttpException in there

Comment: Is this supposed to work in Laravel 8? I can't get it to work in Laravel 8.41.0 :/

Comment: Yes it is, "I can't get it to work" is not very descriptive of the problem you're encountering

Comment: I've managed to get it worse in Laravel 8 but there's no space between "Error" and "404", not ideal for showing to users.

Answer (score 1):

follow @Tofandel answer, my practice is as follows,
Since this question is relatively new I presume you are using `Laravel` version 7 or 8. According to the documentary of [`Error Handling`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors), the correct page rendering method is now

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
    return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

In order to use customised error view, you would have to tell `Laravel` what kind of `Exception` instance your thrown `$exception` is. To overwrite the internal error handling you would want to catch the thrown as a HTTP exception. For these versions the correct Class is as `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\`. Therefore,

1. bring in the handling Class by
   `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;`
   on the top of your `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`
2. modify the default render() method to something like follows in accordance to your scenario,

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
    //
    //
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // return parent::render($request, $exception);
    if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production' && $exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
        }
        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production' && $exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
            return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
        }
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check the docs here https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getcode.php

Try `$exception->getCode()`

Comment: The OP is not referring to the basic php exception so this will not get the correct code

Comment: Have you tried it? The result will be 0 in this case...

Comment: The scope of the question is the http status code e.g. 400/500 etc which is retrieved per the selected answer. `$exception->getCode()` returns the error categorisation code which can be set simply to organise and identify specific errors